# Is there a way to extract year range from wide data?

Tags: stata, panel-data, multiple-databases, stata-macros, wide-format-data

I have a series of wide panel datasets. In each of these, I want to generate a series of new variables. E.g., in Dataset1, I have variables `Car2009 Car2010 Car2011` in a dataset. Using this, I want to create a variable `HadCar2009`, which is 1 if `Car2009` is non-missing, and 0 if missing, similarly `HadCar2010`, and so on. Of course, this is simple to do but I want to do it for multiple datasets which could have different ranges in terms of time. E.g., Dataset2 has variables `Car2005`, `Car2006`, `Car2008`.

These are all very large datasets (I have about 60 such datasets), so I wouldn't want to convert them to long either.

For now, this is what I tried:

```
forval j = 1/2{
  use Dataset`j', clear
  forval i=2005/2011{
     capture gen HadCar`i' = .
     capture replace HadCar`i' = 1 if !missing(Car`i')
     capture replace HadCar`i' = 0 if missing(Car`i')
  }
  save Dataset`j', replace
}
```

This works, but I am reluctant to use `capture`, because perhaps some datasets have a variable called `car2008` instead of `Car2008`, and this would be an error I would like the program to stop at.

Also, the ranges of years across my 60-odd datasets are different. Ideally, I would like to somehow get this range in a local (perhaps somehow using `describe`? I'm not sure) and then just generate these variables using that local with a simple for loop.

But I'm not sure I can do this in Stata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop could be rewritten from

```
forval i=2005/2011{
     capture gen HadCar`i' = .
     capture replace HadCar`i' = 1 if !missing(Car`i')
     capture replace HadCar`i' = 0 if missing(Car`i')
  }
```

to

```
foreach v of var Car???? { 
      gen Had`v' = !missing(`v') 
}
```

noting the fact in Stata that true or false expressions evaluate to 1 or 0 directly.

https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099

https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0087

https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/

This code is going to ignore variables beginning with `car`. There are other ways to check for their existence. However, if there are no variables `Car????` the loop will trigger an error message. A loop over `?ar????` would catch `car????` and `Car????` (but just possibly other variables too).